# Add a value to all Sets (values in a map) in a Map<String, Set<String>>

Tags: java

I have a `Map<String, Set<String>>`. I just need to add a default value `abc` to all the Sets associated with each keys.

In Java 7 I can do something like,

```
    for(Set set : map.values()){
        set.add("abc");
    }
```

Is there any elegant way to do this in Java 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `forEach`:

```
map.values().forEach(set->set.add("abc"));
```

or

```
map.forEach((k,v)->v.add("abc"));
```